# Would, could, V(past simple) usage in the clause after "wish" and "if only"

Tags: grammar

My understanding is that if you refer to a future wish you cannot use the same subjects for "wish" and "would", but instead you may use "could".
For example:

> I wish I **could** attend your wedding next week.

Not *I wish I **would** attend your wedding next week.*

Also, my understanding of **Verb (past simple form)** usage in the clause after **wish** is to express a wish for things that are unreal or impossible to do at present.

However, there's a common saying that is

> I wish I had a lot of money

I wonder if this saying is simply used to express a wish for an unreal thing at present, or it is also acceptable to express a future wish, or I should use another expression such as

> I wish I could have a lot of money in the future

Comment: Your understanding is mistaken. The problem in your example is with the subject "I". .

Comment: There is nothing wrong with "I wish you/he/she/it/they could/would attend your wedding." However, it is an error to use "would" in this construction with the first person singular.as "I" am wishing something that is possible if I decide to do it. [The first person plural (we) might be possible in certain contexts: "I wish we would/could be more united, instead of arguing."]

Comment: Thank you, Greybeard